# Why org-babel-tangle-file tangles source blocks to different files?

Tags: org-mode, org-babel

I try to use `emacs --batch` in Makefile to tangle my `.org` files.

Here's my test org file (t.org)

```
* Another Header

  #+BEGIN_SRC emacs-lisp 
    (message "Hello")
  #+END_SRC

* Header 1

  #+BEGIN_SRC emacs-lisp :tangle yes
    (provide 't)
  #+END_SRC
```

I use this command to try to tangle it to `lisp/t.el`:

```
emacs -Q --batch --eval 'require (quote org))' --eval '(org-babel-tangle-file "t.org" "lisp/t.el" "emacs-lisp")'
```

Instead of get single file (lisp/t.el), I got 2 tangled files:

1. `t.el` at current directory:

   (provide 't)
2. `lisp/t.el`:

   (message "Hello")

Is that the expect behaviour? How could I tangle all the source blocks to single file (`lisp/t.el`)?

Emacs: 25.0.94.1 (Built from source)
Org-mode: 8.3.4
OS: Ubuntu 16.04

Answer (score 2):

From org [documentation](http://orgmode.org/manual/Extracting-source-code.html#Extracting-source-code):

> **:tangle no**
>        The default.  The code block is not included in the tangled 
>   output.
>
> **:tangle yes**
>        Include the code block in the tangled output.  The output file name
>        is the name of the org file with the extension ‘.org’ replaced by
>        the extension for the block language.

And from `org-babel-tangle-file` doc string (emphasis mine)

> Optional argument TARGET-FILE can be used to specify a **default**
>   export file for all source blocks.

So your second block having `:tangle yes` implicitly specify the filename to be used for this block.

Also, my understanding (and this is not exactly obvious) is that the file name provided to `org-babel-tangle-file` changes the default for the lack of a `:tangle` argument from `:tangle no` to `:tangle filename` with the provided filename.

To tangle all your blocks to the same file, simply remove the `:tangle yes` argument from the blocks that have it.

Answer (score 1):

> Is that the expect behavior?

Yes.

> How could I tangle all the source blocks to single file (lisp/t.el)?

Make all blocks consistent with :tangle yes or do not give the lisp/t.el optional target file in the batch mode. In short don't mix and match different tangle options for blocks in the same file and expect same output.